# PDO return array('value1','value2')

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

Im using a select sql statement PDO fetchData,

```
$user = 'admin';
sql = 'SELECT AccessPage FROM accessrights where UserName = '$user'';
```

in database the result would look like this:

```
-----------
Access Page
-----------
 - index

 + create

 - update
```

And I will store it inside a variable $result

How can I make the $result format to an array just like this?

```
$result = array('index','create','update');
```

Another question,

I used the codes in my function: but when I var_dump, it retun a array(0) { }  value.

Here is my function:

```
    $user = CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->user->name);

    $connectionString[0] = Yii::app()->params['dbhandler2'];
    $dbhandler3 = new DBHandler($connectionString[0]);
    $dbhandler3->open();

    $dbhandler3->prepare("SELECT AccessPage FROM accessrights where UserName ='$user'");
    $dbhandler3->execute();
    $this->result2 = $dbhandler3->fetchAllData();
    $dbhandler3->close();

    $yourarrayname = array();
    while ($row = $dbhandler3->fetchAllData()) {
        $yourarrayname[] = $row['AccessPage'];
    }

    $this->access = $yourarrayname;
```

Comment: You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the below code

```
 $user = 'admin';
 $sql = "SELECT AccessPage FROM accessrights where UserName = '$user'";
 $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $sth->execute();

 /* Fetch all of the values of the first column */
 $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
 print_r($result); // the $result will be array  array('index','create','update');
```

Comment: WOw I used this code and It works fine Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `index`, `create`, and `update` are column values and you want them in a "plain" array. The default is to store the result as integer and column-name keys. You want to set the fetchmode to integer keys: `$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` or `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)`. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all  I am assuming that You have just one column Accesspage
and in that column you have already saved three rows index, create, update. When you searched for **Accesspage** values for a user `$user`. This will return values that are assigned to $user.

```
$user = 'admin';
$sql = 'SELECT AccessPage FROM accessrights where UserName = '$user'';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

Now this $result is an associative array with key '**AccessPage**'

If you want to make an array then you should try like this

```
$yourarrayname=array();
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
 $yourarrayname[]= $row['AccessPage'] ; 
}

print_r($yourarrayname);
```

Comment: Always accept answer to get immense help from stackoverflowers!

Comment: Oh I tried the code you gave to me last time, but it only returns an empty array, I edited my code at the top